# Cannot get jQuery UI datepicker to appear on two tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, highcharts, datepicker

Please take a look at my jsFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/MrSnrub/w8rem1be/

The two datepickers both appear successfully on the first ("Stock Price") tab. But neither of them appear on the second ("Percentage Change") tab. However, they are both being called using relatively similar code (as part of the Highstock object creation process):

First set of datepickers:

```
function(chart) {

  // apply the date pickers
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#tabs-1')).datepicker()
  }, 0)
});
```

Second set of datepickers:

```
function(chart) {

  // apply the date pickers
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('input.highcharts-range-selector', $('#tabs-2')).datepicker()
  }, 0)
});
```

What am I doing wrong in the second function call?

Comment: Looks like your datetime inputs on the second tab could not be found. Have a look at the image from console. The first one returns expected inputs, the second one returns null and thus you do not have datetime picker created. It appears that your inputs do not have needed classes.

If you type $('input', $('#tabs-2')) in console you'll see there is only one input element and that one is of type 'hidden'. Thank you @Barmar for pointing out this is more in comment form.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `div#div-highstock-stock-price-chart` you have a div with the needed inputs inside it.

Add the same / similar html markup inside `div#div-highstock-percentage-change-chart` that the datepicker can attach to.

Credit to Nesaje for seeing this first.

Comment: Highcharts is creating the divs, not his HTML  Why is highcharts creating the 2nd set of controls differently than the 1st?  The setup looks the same.

Comment: What "inputs" should I be looking for? I write console.log($('#div-highstock-stock-price-chart')); and there's like a hundred different properties listed.

Comment: @Barbara right, highchart is creating those elements. I 'm afraid I don't know how to fix highchart.

Comment: @MrSnrub just visually inspect #tabs-1 > #div-highstock-stock-price-chart > first child div (no id/class, only inline css) > input (x2), then find that div with inputs inside #tabs-2. It's not there. Comment out the datepicker codes. The date inputs in #tabs-1 are editable, the inputs in #tab-2 are not. So it's either a html markup issue, something with your percentage change setup, or a bug... a highchart expert may be able to answer that...

Answer (score 0):

This is because charts are not rendered properly if they are hidden.

This bug is fixed on bugfix branch of Highstock. Related issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5231

Working demo using mentioned Highstock version:
http://jsfiddle.net/w8rem1be/26/

```
<script src="http://github.highcharts.com/bugfix/highstock.js"></script>
```